# How can I get my pi3 to consistently display to the monitor?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, raspberry-pi-os

I have a pi that will not stay awake and display to the monitor consistently. After 10 minutes it will blank. Here are the methods I have tried so far:
Adding xscreensaver, and editing it in the menu that way but every time I try to install xscreensaver it will error out and not let me install. Replacing the monitor and HDMI cable Editing sudo nano /boot/config.txt and removing the # from #hdmi_force_hotplug=1 #hdmi_drive=2 Editing sudo raspi-config Editing sudo nano /boot/cmdline.txt

Comment: `every time I try to install xscreensaver it will error out and not let me install` - what is the error? how are you trying to install it?

Comment: Have you adjusted your power saving settings?   Sounds like maybe you want to disable the screensaver?  But then why are you trying to install a screensaver?